# How to get the correct offset top value from webkit (Chrome/Safari) with jQuery? Webkit bug?

Tags: jquery, webkit, position, offset

I'm working on code that programmatically positions a div to give the appearance of scrolling. All works fine when using Firefox and Internet Explorer (believe it or not). However, I'm getting bogus values from webkit browsers (Chrome/Safari). It appears to have something to do with whether an element has content. I'm calculating the position of an empty anchor element. Webkit seems to get it right *only* when the element has visible content. So, I could work around this by having some content in my anchor. However, that messes up my layout and feels like a kludge. Also, I'd like to log a bug, if that is indeed what I'm dealing with. Below is a sample document to illustrate the issue. Open it in the different browsers to see what I mean. Much thanks in advance! :-)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>What's Up with Webkit Anchor offset()?</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var offsetAlert = function(calledBy){
            var anchor = jQuery("a#anchor");
            var span = jQuery("span#test");
            var subheading = jQuery("span#targetSubHeading");
            if (anchor.length == 1 && span.length == 1 && subheading.length == 1)
            {
                alert("offsetAlert(calledBy=["+calledBy+"])\n\tanchor.offset().top=["+anchor.offset().top+"]\n\nspan.offset().top=["+span.offset().top+"]\n\nsubheading.offset().top=["+subheading.offset().top+"]");
            }

        };

        $(document).ready(function (){offsetAlert("jQuery.ready");});
    </script>
</head>
<body style="background-color:#c6cbd1; margin:0px; padding:0px; border:none;" onload="javascript:offsetAlert('body.onload');">
    <div>
        <a name="top"></a><h2>Heading</h2>
        This is the phenomemaly interesting text.
        <br ><br >This is the phenomemaly interesting text.
        <br ><br >This is the phenomemaly interesting text.
        <br ><br >Internal Links: <a href="#a1">Sub-heading 1</a>, <a href="#a2">Sub-heading 2</a>, <a href="#a3">Sub-heading 3</a>, <a href="#anchor">Target Sub-heading</a>
        <br ><br ><b><a id="a1"></a>Sub-heading 1</b>
        <br >This is the phenomemaly interesting text. 
        <br><a href="#top">top</a>
        <br ><br ><a id="a2"></a><b>Sub-heading 2</b>
        <br >This is the phenomemaly interesting text.
        <br><a href="#top">top</a>
        <br ><br ><b><a id="a3"></a>Sub-heading 3</b>
        <br >This is the phenomemaly interesting text.
        <br><a href="#top">top</a>
        <br ><br ><span class="anchor" id="test"><a id="anchor"></a></span><span id="targetSubHeading" style="font-weight:bold;">Target Sub-heading</span>
        <br >This is the phenomemaly interesting text.
        <br><a href="#top">top</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Okay, here's an update. Thanks to Charles for the answer below. I updated my example to function to illustrate both the problem and the workaround I came up with based on Charles' answer. This seems to work, but I'm still wondering if I should report this is a bug.

```
var offsetAlert = function(calledBy){
    var anchor = jQuery("a#anchor");
    var subheading = jQuery("span#targetSubHeading");
    var displayCss = anchor.css("display");
    anchor.css("display", "block");
    var alteredOffset = anchor.offset();
    anchor.css("display", (displayCss ? displayCss : ""));
    if (anchor.length == 1 && subheading.length == 1)
    {
        alert("displayCss=["+displayCss+"]\nalteredOffset.top=["+alteredOffset.top+"]\noffsetAlert(calledBy=["+calledBy+"])\n\tanchor.offset().top=["+anchor.offset().top+"]\n\nsubheading.offset().top=["+subheading.offset().top+"]");
    }
};
```

Thanks!

---

Here's hopefully the last update. I checked Webkit and didn't find this bug. So I added a new bug and a link to this question. Hopefully, this will get some attention and eventually get fixed. Here's the link: http://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=72524

BTW - I briefly had on here a link to an existing bug, but it turned out that it was for offsetHeight and not offsetTop.

Comment: I'm glad you got it sorted out. I tried searching for a bug report too, without success. I sure hope it gets fixed. All the best /Charles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see, this affects any inline-element without content. Changing the span-element to any block element or adding display: block; to the span-tag gives me the same values as in IE.

Comment: Charles, I also tried removing the span element and changing the a element to have display:block and it worked. It does impact the decimal values I get from Firefox, but both round to the same pixel. So, this is a decent work around. I don't want to mark it as answered yet though, because I'm hoping someone will confirm if it's a WebKit bug. THANKS!

Comment: Getting the `.offset().top` of `<br>`s also returns `0`