# offset().top not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

Having problem offset().top not working in Safari. Works fine on all other browsers but seems to break in Safari. Any suggestions?

```
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        collapseNav();
    });

    function collapseNav() { 
        if ($(".navbar").offset().top > 50 ) {
            // code here
        } else {
            // code here
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126648/how-to-get-the-correct-offset-top-value-from-webkit-chrome-safari-with-jquery  . Is it related to your issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this issue like this

```js
// as of 1.4.2 the mobile safari reports wrong values on offset()
// http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/6446
// remove once it's fixed
if (/webkit.*mobile/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
  (function($) {
    $.fn.offsetOld = $.fn.offset;
    $.fn.offset = function() {
      var result = this.offsetOld();
      result.top -= window.scrollY;
      result.left -= window.scrollX;
      return result;
    };
  })(jQuery);
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the effort it didn't work for me. I didn't find a work around I'll post it below.

Answer (score 0):

Found a work around using $(window).scrollTop(). So it looks like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    collapseNav();
});

function collapseNav() { 
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 50 ) {
        // code here
    } else {
        // code here
    }
}
```